# DateTime is not valid error

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

In my model I have this :

```
public DateTime ProjectTime { get; set; }
```

I added a jQueryUI datepicker to my View. When I pick a date using datepicker, I get this :

> The value '02/18/2016' is not valid for ProjectTime .

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: where you get this error?? Is it an exception or javascript error?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao It's a warning in the website, it appears next to textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked, when I changed ProjectTime to this :

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString =
       "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}",
        ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ProjectTime { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Format of date you pass to projectTime should match the format of date which you get from Datetime.Now property. Otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: I need to use datepicker.

Comment: $( ".selector" ).datepicker({

dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"

});